# List DropBox folder users via API (Windows)?

Tags: windows, dropbox, dropbox-api

I can list the files in a DropBox folder via API (Windows). But is there any way to list the folder users (i.e., who I have shared it with)?  There does not appear to be, but I was hoping someone stumbled across something.

We are using the C#.Net platform, but any of the Windows 7/8 supported platforms will do.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to get this via the API, sorry about that